# How do I load a file from bower_component within AngularJS UI router?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, oclazyload

I would like to load a file when a specific URL is hit, but I didn't have any success with it yet:

This is how my code looks like:

```
.state('admin.resources', {
            url: '/resources',
            templateUrl: 'views/admin/resources.html',
            controller: 'ResourceController as res',
            resolve: {
                loadMyFiles: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'venture',
                        files: [
                            'bower_components/angular-ui-tinymce/src/tinymce.js'
                        ]
                    })
                }
            }
        })
```

It works all fine if I include it on the index.html like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-tinymce/src/tinymce.js"></script>
```

I don't want to load id from index.html as I don't want that page to be loaded once the site is loaded. I need that script on a separate page.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the oclazyload, you need to put it in the `resolve` property:

```
$stateProvider.state('index', {
  url: "/", // root route
  views: {
    "lazyLoadView": {
      controller: 'AppCtrl', // This view will use AppCtrl loaded below in the resolve
      templateUrl: 'partials/main.html'
    }
  },
  resolve: { // Any property in resolve should return a promise and is executed before the view is loaded
    loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
      // you can lazy load files for an existing module
             return $ocLazyLoad.load('js/AppCtrl.js');
    }]
  }
});
```

All is explained and well-documented in *[With your router](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/with-your-router)*.